# How do I get a generator-expression file's basename?

Tags: string, cmake, filenames, file-extension, cmake-custom-command

Here's a custom command we find in the CMake documentation:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET foo POST_BUILD
  COMMAND someHasher -i "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>"
                     -o "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>.hash"
  VERBATIM)
```

suppose that, instead of adding `.hash`, I want to replace any existing extension with `.hash`. I would need some way to strip the extension from `$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>`... how should I do this? Can I do better than full-blown regexp matching?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html -> `TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME`

Comment: Yup, that will do it. Now for the harder problem of OBJECT libraries not being usable as targets for POST_BUILD...

Comment: Yes, but that is odd - OBJECT is just a collection of object files. If you want to generate something, do not use `POST_BUILD` - depend on files, depend on object files. I would also refactor that custom command to `OUTPUT "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>.hash"` instead of `POST_BUILD`. I.e. build dependencies on _files_. `POST_BUILD` is great like for showing stats `size $<TARGET_FILE:myExe>`, if you want to generate files I recommend just doing `OUTPUT` and another `add_custom_target`.

Comment: @KamilCuk : Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70525167/1593077).

Answer (score 2):

(due to @KamilCuk)

Use `TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME`, like so:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET foo POST_BUILD
  COMMAND someHasher -i "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>"
                     -o "$<TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME:myExe>.hash"
  VERBATIM)
```