# How can I build a fatbin file using CMake?

Tags: cmake, cuda, buildconfiguration, cmake-custom-command, fatbin

I want to build a fatbin file from my `.cu` source file, using CMake.

I've tried this:

```
add_library(dummy_lib OBJECT my_src.cu)
set_property(TARGET dummy_lib PROPERTY CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET dummy_lib POST_BUILD
  COMMAND nvcc -fatbin 
     -o "$<TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME::dummy_lib>.fatbin" 
     "$<TARGET_FILE:dummy_lib>"
  VERBATIM)
```

Unfortunately - this doesn't work, since you can have a `POST_BUILD` dependency on an `OBJECT`-type library. However, if I remove the `OBJECT` property, then I can't use `CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON` on it...

Then I'd though I'd try the `OUTPUT` version of `add_custom_command()`:

```
add_library(dummy_lib OBJECT my_src.cu)
set_property(TARGET dummy_lib PROPERTY CUDA_PTX_COMPILATION ON)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT my_src.fatbin
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER} -fatbin -o my_src.fatbin "$<TARGET_FILE:dummy_lib>"
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY dummy_lib
)
```

and this doesn't trigger any errors... but doesn't build the fatbin file either.

How do I get CMake to build my fatbin? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the PTX intermediate file, and do this instead:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT my_src.fatbin
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER} -fatbin 
        -o ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/foo.fatbin 
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_src.cu"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY my_src.cu
)
add_custom_target(dummy ALL DEPENDS my_src.fatbin)
```