# How can I generalize a custom command into a generic-make-rule-like construct?

Tags: cmake, cuda, build-automation, build-rules, fatbin

In this question:

[How can I build a fatbin file using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70525167/1593077)

we saw how to formulate a pair of `add_custom_command()` and `add_custom_target()` commands, for building a `.fatbin` file out of a `.cu` file:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT my_src.fatbin
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER} -fatbin -o foo.fatbin 
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_src.cu"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY my_src.cu
)
add_custom_target(dummy ALL DEPENDS my_src.fatbin)
```

. The details of what these files are and how they are used is immaterial to this question (I hope); what I would like to do is *generalize* these two specific commands so that I don't just build `my_src.fatbin` from `my_src.cu`, but so that I can easily build any `.cu` file I specify into a `.fatbin` file. Essentially, the equivalent of Make's:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.fatbin : $(SRCDIR)/%.cu
        $(CUDA_COMPILER) $(CUDA_CPP_FLAGS) -fatbin -o $@ $<
```

What's the appropriate idiom for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a function is the right approach. Something like this? :

```
function(add_fatbin target_basename source_file)
    # TODO: Should I check target_basename isn't a full path?
    set(target_filename "${target_basename}.fatbin")
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${target_filename}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER} -fatbin -o "${target_filename}"
            "${source_file}"
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${source_file}"
    )
    add_custom_target("${target_basename}_fatbin_tgt" ALL DEPENDS "${target_filename}")
endfunction()
```

Comment: You could use `get_filename_component(target_filename "${target_basename}.fatbin" BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BIRARY_DIR})`, if you want to ensure an absolute path and similar for the source file. But if you want to allow both absolute and relative paths to be specified, you should also extract the file name to determine the name of the custom target: `get_filename_component(custom_target_prefix ${target_basename} NAME)`... If you want to allow reuse of the functionality accross several subdirectories, you may need to find a way of generating unique names for the custom targets btw...

Comment: @fabian: Ok, but - is this the basic approach people use? Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other possibility of generating a make rule(or equivalent), unless there's some specific functionality provided by a cmake module that provides similar functionality or builtin functionality like qt mocking functionality. Also I'm not familiar with cuda so I cannot make any statements on whether the dependencies could be expressed in a better way, like adding those to a existing executable target or something like this...

Comment: @fabian: Anyway... I want to allow the same kind of invocation as with `add_executable()`. Could I trouble you to edit the answer to make your suggestion more concrete?